# Not sure how to deal with ListView IllegalStateException: “The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification”

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, asynchronous

Sorry for a brick of a code but I read that I need to run something on UI thread, how do I do that?  private ArrayList JsonFIveDays(String weatherSearchResults) is where I set my listview adapter if that helps.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: have a look here [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to notify the adapter whenever you do changes in the weatherArrayList.

For Example,

```
weatherAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

But in your case to use like that you have to declare the weatherAdapter as a property of the class.

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to notify adapter that you changed data with `notifyDataSetChanged()`. You can do that in `setData` method after changing data.